# setting a probablity for an action or game event

Tags: python, probability

i want to set Win *probability* of 70% and a lose *probability* of 30 % for a *specific game playing event or action* how do i attain this in python any library for this to make this task easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way coud be using a uniformly distributed random number between {0-1} and assigning win when the value is <= 0.7 and lose the rest of cases:

```
import random
random_number = random.random()
if random_number <= 0.7:
    print('Win')
else:
    print('Lose')
```